# Add User ID to Sequelize Audit Fields (createdBy, updatedBy, deletedBy)

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

What is the best way to adding a User ID as an audit field within Sequelize?  I'd like to capture the user ID of anyone who creates, updates, or deletes a record.  For example:

```
{
  tableName: 'user_profile',
  schema: 'authentication',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  auditUser: '_u',
  createdAt: '_c',
  updatedAt: '_v',
  deletedAt: '_d'
}
```

... or ...

```
{
  tableName: 'user_profile',
  schema: 'authentication',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  createdBy: '_cu',
  createdAt: '_c',
  updatedBy: '_vu',
  updatedAt: '_v',
  deletedBy: '_du',
  deletedAt: '_d'
}
```